# My datatable shows "No data available in table".My web api works fine and returns json string.What am i missing?

Tags: datatables

This is my JavaScript code. My table id is `tblEmployee`.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#tblEmployee').DataTable({       
        ajax: {
            "url": "http://localhost:57507/api/Employee/Get", 
            "dataSrc": ""
        },  
        columns : [{ data: 'Employee_Id' }, { data: 'Project_Id' }, { data:        'Grade_Id' }, { data: 'Site_Id' },{ data: 'Location_Id' },{ data: 'StartDate'   }, { data: 'EndDate' }, { data: 'BillRate' }, { data: 'Role' },
        ]
    });
});
```

This is the data from my database which the web API calls:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can we see your data or an example of it? Perhaps work up a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are setting the `dataSrc = ""` . As per [data-tables docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) `dataSrc` should be set to empty string if you are reading via ajax from a **file**. Since you are accessing the api to get a json string try something like this

A working [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntcwust8/159/) (with another Url)

```
  var url = 'http://localhost:57507/api/Employee/Get';

 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     'processing': true,
     'serverSide': true,
     'ajax': {
         type: 'POST',
         'url': url,
         'data': function(d) {
             console.log(d.order);
             return JSON.stringify(d);
         }
     },
     columns: [{
         data: 'Employee_Id'
     }, {
         data: 'Project_Id'
     }, {
         data: 'Grade_Id'
     }, {
         data: 'Site_Id'
     }, {
         data: 'Location_Id'
     }, {
         data: 'StartDate'
     }, {
         data: 'EndDate'
     }, {
         data: 'BillRate'
     }, {
         data: 'Role'
     }, ]

 });
```